# What is the easiest way to find a Juanito in Tropico 4?

Tags: achievements, tropico-4

I would like to find a Juanito (someone named Juanito) in Tropico 4, what is the easiest way to do so?

I am trying to go through the list of all tropico born citizens, but it is just takes too long, is there an easier way to find Jaunito?

Comment: How many citizens do you have?  I never had more than a hundred, so it seems that shouldn't be too hard...

Comment: 1300+ and could not find any Jaunito's

Answer (score 3):

It may seem like cheating but here is what you can do...

Rename a person(aged 29 years, male, no spouse or other family member, garbageman) to "Juanito" and eliminate him.

And then you should get the achievement.

If you don't feel like "Cheating" here is a tip...

His origin has also been known to be from Cuba or Spain.